# Wkhtmltopdf libpng15.so error with Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-6, wicked-pdf

I have recently upgraded my Rails application from 6.0 to 6.1 and after upgrading whenever I am trying to generate a PDF, I get this error:

`RuntimeError: Failed to execute: ["/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--orientation", "Landscape", "--margin-top", "25", "--margin-bottom", "10", "--header-spacing", "3", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20210506-22237-1tx5wdw.html", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20210506-22237-1fo4wp6.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20210506-22237-1c7ctor.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20210506-22237-1c2hpwj.pdf"] Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf_centos_7_amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried following the steps by following this link: https://majestic.cloud/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-amazon-linux/ to install libpng manually but problem remains as-is

`# wkhtmltopdf https://majestic.cloud majestic.pdf /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf_centos_7_amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Here's what my Gemfile looks like:

```
ruby '2.6.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.3.1'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Here's my `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`

```
if Rails.env.production?
  WickedPdf.config = {
    exe_path: '/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
  }
end
```

And since the app is hosted on ElasticBeanstalk the permission has been set via ebextensions

```
container_commands:
  03_set_wkhtmltopdf_binary_permissions:
    command: "chmod -R 777 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue came because of version mismatch. More to follow here: https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/issues/110

Below worked for me:

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '0.12.6'
```

`Gemfile.lock`

```
  wicked_pdf (2.1.0)
    activesupport
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.6)
wicked_pdf (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (= 0.12.6)
```

`.ebextensions/commands.config`

```
03_set_wkhtmltopdf_binary_permissions:
  command: "chmod -R 777 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6/bin/"
```